# Is it possible to anti-alias line ends in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, graphics, antialiasing

I'm drawing some 2D lines in OpenGL (using the AGL API). I've turned on line anti-aliasing using `GL_LINE_SMOOTH` and I've set `GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT` to `GL_NICEST`.

So for example, here's a magnified view of a diagonal line<sup>*</sup>:

[image: Line with anti-aliased edges]
<sub>(source: [whileyouweregone.co.uk](http://whileyouweregone.co.uk/images/stackoverflow/good-aa.png))</sub>

However, the problem is that my code draws some shapes which are built up of large numbers of vertical lines, and it seems the end points of lines are *not* anti-aliased. Here's one of those:

[image: Lines without anti-aliased endpoints]
<sub>(source: [whileyouweregone.co.uk](http://whileyouweregone.co.uk/images/stackoverflow/bad-aa.png))</sub>

(Each step you can see is made up of 10 vertical lines, with the x coordinates of each line incrementing in steps of 1.0, and the y coordinates incrementing in steps of 0.1.)

Is there a way of getting OpenGL to also anti-alias the lines' end points?

**Edit:**

As per [Calvin1602's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793349/is-it-possible-to-anti-alias-line-ends-in-opengl/7793417#7793417), I've tried removing the `GL_LINE_SMOOTH` stuff and am instead enabling MSAA by adding the following to my AGL attributes array:

`AGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS_ARB, 1, AGL_SAMPLES_ARB, 4, AGL_MULTISAMPLE`

...and calling:

`glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE_ARB);`

However, I still have the same problem. The line edges are anti-aliased (in a slightly different way), but the end-points aren't.

<sub>* Screenshots are from a Mac Pro running OS X 10.7.1 with a ATI Radeon HD 5770 1024 MB.</sub>

**Edit 2:**

Using MSAA doesn't work for me, but simply drawing all my lines as very thin rectangles [as suggested by ltjax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793349/is-it-possible-to-anti-alias-line-ends-in-opengl/7793410#7793410) seems to have done the trick. (I didn't need to use a texture or a gradient.)

Comment: Are the endpoint coordinates integral values or floating-point?

Comment: @Brett They're floating point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, full-screen anti-aliasing will do this for you. For example, [multi-sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multisample_anti-aliasing) will work and is widely supported. If you want to stick with just anti-aliased lines, you can emulate it by drawing quads instead (which are slightly larger than your line) and using either a predefined "gradient" texture or a shader that evaluates the distance from the real line.

Comment: Thanks. Any pointers on how to enable multi-sampling? I'm struggling to find any information other than the `ARB_multisample`, spec, which doesn't appear to include any sample code of how to use it.

Comment: Using MSAA didn't work for me, but drawing thin (untextured) rectangles instead of lines did. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try disabling the `GL_LINE_SMOOTH` stuff, which hasn't a well defined behaviour across drivers, and use MSAA (multi-sample anti-aliasing).

This is enabled at context creation; it depends on the framework you're using. GLFW ? SDL? Other ? Home-made ?

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't appear to be doing it for me. I've updated my question accordingly. Am I doing something wrong with my MSAA setup?

Comment: If the edges are antialiased, and line_smooth is diabled, then MSAA works. You should swich to ltjax's solution of drawing quads instead, then. Try without shader first, it might be enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could always implement ["Fast Antialiasing Using Prefiltered Lines on Graphics Hardware"](http://people.csail.mit.edu/ericchan/articles/prefilter/).